# Print between two patterns only when the first pattern occurs for the second time

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to print output between two pattern and first pattern should be second time matching in file.

Example -

`test.txt`

```
start one
text_1   
end
start two
text_2
end 
start three
text_3
end
```

Here first pattern is `start` and second pattern is `end`. Pattern `start` should be second time pattern matching in file.
Then 
output should be

```
start two
text_2
end
```

Comment: If the file format is always the same you could simply use `sed -n '4,/end/p' filename`

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, easily extensible to any n<sup>th</sup> record:

```
awk '/start/ && ++n == 2, /end/' < file
```

would print the lines from the second occurrence of `start` to the first occurrence of `end` after that.

To print the second `start` to `end` record (would make a difference if there are `start`,`start`,`end` sequences):

```
awk '
  /start/, /end/ {
    if (!seen) {seen = 1; n++}
    if (n == 2) print
    if (/end/) seen = 0
  }' < file
```

Or:

```
awk '
  !inside && /start/ {inside = 1; n++}
  !inside {next}
  n == 2
  /end/ {inside = 0}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/n;/start/,/end/{p;/end/q}' file
```

Explanation:

- `-n` supresses output
- first `/start/,/end/n` extract first start-to-end block, but do nothing (via `n`)
- then for the second start-to-end block `/start/,/end/` print and quit as soon as end is reached `p;/end/q`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case - when the input consists only of `/start/,/end/` blocks you can simply do

```
sed '1,/end/d;//q' infile
```

If there are other lines between those blocks (not matching `end`) then

```
sed '1,/end/d;/start/,/end/!d;/end/q' infile
```

For the more general case when the block to be extracted is the `n`th one you could run:

```
n=5
awk  -vc=$n '/start/{i++};{if (i==c){print;if (/end/){exit}}}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne '
   /^start/,/^end/!d; # skip non-interesting block
   /^start/H;         # increment hold counter
   G;/\n.*\n.*\n/!d;  # check if 2nd block reached?
   P;/^end/q;         # we"re in 2nd block so print & quit on /end/
' yourfile

perl -l -0777ne 'print+(/^start.*?\nend[^\n]*$/msg)[1]' yourfile
```